# What is the stdout output in stream-redirection labs?

Tags: command-line, streaming, redirect, stdout

Inside the ‘stream-redirection’ folder there is a program called ‘program’. When you run this it will output to stdout and stderr.

What is the stdout output?

I have tried  `./program`, but it did not work.

It just showed the following output

```
    daf091fb23c8941linux@stream-redirection:~$
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your question to explain: What is the `stream-redirection` folder and `program`? I don’t have such a folder on my Ubuntu (`find / -type d -name stream-redirection` gives no result).

Answer (score 0):

I did

```
./program | cat 1>output.txt | vim output.txt
```

That gave me a token... but the same approach doesn't work for std error...I'm stuck on the next bit.

Comment: just got it to work!

Comment: ./program 2>test | vim test

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please [edit] your answer to post a correction, don’t use comments. Could you explain what does your command do and how it solves the question?

Comment: thanks, I think it was showing the whole thing stdout and stderr if we use ./program. But my lack of knowledge could not figure that out.